# Failing transaction when calling a funciton from geth console

Tags: smartcontracts, geth, remix

I am discovering the blockchain world step by step, but I am facing a problem that I can't solve.

I am using this simple smart contract from the Solidity documentation:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint storedData;

    function set(uint x) public {
        storedData = x;
    }

    function get() public view returns (uint) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

I compile the code with Remix, and when I deploy it on JavascriptVM, everything works fine, I can change the stored value.

However, when I deploy it on a private geth node (using web3deploy), the contract is successfully mined but when I try to use the `set()` function `storage.set(4,{from:eth.accounts[0]})` it always returns "**gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction**", even if the account has sufficient funds.

I feel that I am missing something important but I can't figure it out.
Someone help would be appreciated! thks!

Comment: I have solved the problem. I have updated geth, and added "byzantiumBlock": 0, "constantinopleBlock":0, "petersburgBlock": 0 in the genesis file of my private network. I am not sure to understand the reason of the problem, but it works fine now.

Comment: Can you provide us your genesis.json used for your private geth ?

Comment: Here is the genesis file that I now use for my private blockchain, and works for the deployment of smart contracts: 


{
 "config": {
  "chainId": 23052019,
  "homesteadBlock": 0,
  "eip150Block": 0,
  "eip155Block": 0,
  "eip158Block": 0,
  "byzantiumBlock": 0, 
  "constantinopleBlock":0,
  "petersburgBlock": 0
 },
 "alloc": {},
 "difficulty" : "0x4",
 "gasLimit"   : "0x8880000"
}

Comment: To interact with your smartcontract you may want web3 to know your contract address. Can you please show us your code used before web3 calling storage.set